# "All but" - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I actually have a very naive question. When someone says

> All but five people have left the town.

What does it actually mean? Have 5 people left the town or has everyone else left, with only 5 people remaining?

Comment: "All but" means "all except".

Comment: You mean question, not doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definition of [but](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but):

> other than (Merriam-Webster)

A definition of [all](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all):

> the whole number or sum of (Merriam-Webster)

In *All but five people have left the town*, *all* represents the total number of people that were in the town, *5* denotes how many people didn't leave, and *but* creates the condition for how to use those two sums in relation to each other.

Answer (score 2):

> [all but](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+but) something:
>
> - Everyone or everything except those mentioned. (The Free Dictionary)

Your sentence means: "Everyone *except five people* left the town."

All but the weakest plants survived the hot weather. (All plants except the weakest...)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else left, those five stayed.

On the other hand, **all but** is an idiomatic phrase which means **almost**, **nearly**:

> He was all but dead.